# How to integrate with a matrix in the measure?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

I've been given the following integral (actually a path integral from quantum field theory).

$$ Z(a;N) = \int d^{2n}M.exp(-\frac{1}{2}tr(M^2)-\frac{a}{M}tr(M^4)) $$
where M is a square matrix of size $N^2$. The measure $d^{2n}M$ represents an integral over the real and imaginary parts of each entry of M.

The question then asks one to show that $Z(a;N)/Z(0;N)$ can be reduced to an integral over the eigenvalues $\{\lambda_i\}$ of $M$. It gives the hint that the measure if invariant under diagonalisation.

My question is, what does integrating with respect to $M$ mean here? Does one integrate with respect to each element in the matrix separately?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know enough about physics to answer this, but $\text{tr}(M^k)=\sum_i\lambda_i^k$, so if you treat $d^{2n}M$ as just $d\lambda_1...d\lambda_n$ or the equivalent for real and complex parts, you might be able to break the integral up into a product of integrals.

Comment: That's what I've been thinking, but I'm not sure how valid it is to break the $d^{2N}M$ into the product $d\lambda_1 ... d\lambda_n$. Do you have a justification by any chance?

Comment: well you really just need to figure out what is meant by the notation $d^{2n}M$, maybe it's defined in your book or your professor's notes or something.